# ListBox with checkbox in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to have checkboxes in listbox options using PHP and MYSQL. options are coming from database with id and name

Comment: I know how to add options to select with multiple. But I want to place checkboxes in front of options

Comment: Click the "edit" link (below the question) to update your question, instead of posting a comment.

Answer (score 1):

A listbox, in a webpage, is the usual expression of a select element with the multiple attribute set.

You can't have checkboxes inside select options.

You can fake it by using a regular list…

```
<ul>
    <li> <label> <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="1"> One </label> </li>
    <li> <label> <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="2"> Two </label> </li>
</ul>
```

… and then styling it to look like a listbox (making sure you `display: block` the labels so the click target covers the width of the box).